# How to test pagination of Instagram's API in sandbox mode

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am currently using the Instagram API in sandbox mode. I want to get all of the media a user has published. For this purpose I need the pagination feature, that the API offers, when a user has lots of media.

I have code that should paginate through the results via the "next_url" property. But I have no way to test my code, as the API doesn't provide the pagination feature when in sandbox mode.

Any ideas how to test the API's pagination?

Answer (score 0):

**edit:**
Now I realized that you didn't mention the endpoint

I think are not able to use these APIs that need scopes other than basic. I tried the same test few weeks ago and only was able to get a media that I recently shared. The old medias never appeared.

They've changed API policy, to avoid users using 3rd party apps instead Instagram app.